# How to extract selected area of the gui component to PDF in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I need to make the tool  like Snagit and to  take the picture  the selected area of  the component. I'm searching  how to  make  this  tool in Qt.

I  firstly prefer using Qt native library but if  there is no library which fullfills this  requirement, any good c++ libray can be accepted for me.

Any  help will  be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand exactly what you want. I assume you want to take a screen shot ? and then put this picture into a PDF document.

To take a screenshot with Qt, have a look at this :

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.0/widgets-screenshot.html

This will show you how to take a screenshot (using [QDesktopWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdesktopwidget.html)) and get a `QPixmap`.

You can then display this `QPixmap` into a [QTextDocument](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtextdocument.html) (see [QTextDocument::addResource](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qtextdocument.html#addResource)) and print this document into a PDF file. Something like this :

```
QPrinter MyPrinter(QPrinter::HighResolution);
MyPrinter.setOutputFormat(QPrinter::PdfFormat);
MyPrinter.setOutputFileName("test.pdf");
MyPrinter.setPageSize(QPrinter::Letter);
MyPrinter.setColorMode(QPrinter::GrayScale);
MyPrinter.setOrientation(QPrinter::Landscape);

MyTextDocument.print(&MyPrinter);
```